# what is the reasonable time for waiting in setSoTimeout

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am writing a program that requires reading form socket as the following:

```
socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(domain, port);
socket.setSoTimeout(5000); 
socket.startHandshake();
```

I don't have previous experience in socket programming. I need to know if 5 seconds is reasonable time for waiting before throwing an error ? I need to set a time in which I don't lose an opportunity to make a connections.

The second question is: When the timer begins, does it stop once the reading starts ? Or, should I consider the time the program needs to complete the reading ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question is basically meaningless. You set a read timeout based on your expectation of the average server response time plus how much extra time you are prepared to wait before deciding there is a problem. Only you have the information to quantify that in the case of your application, but certainly 5s is way too short. One rule of thumb is to use double or triple the expected response time, depending on the variance, but it's really up to you to decide.

To answer your second question, the timer starts when you enter read(), and stops when the first byte of data arrives or the timeout expires.